# Can dockerconfigjson handle registry subdomains?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, artifactory, kubernetes-secrets

Imagine, I had a private image registry **myregistry.corp** with several (sub-) repositories e.g. **project1.myregistry.corp** and **project2.myregistry.corp**.

If I want to have one common imagePullingSecret, do I need to specify each of them in its dockerconfigjson or is Kubernetes smart enough to find the "closest" specified top level domain for a given domain (e.g. if I want to pull from project1.myregistry.corp/myapp)?

```
{
  "auths": {
    "myregistry.corp": {
      "username": "my-user",
      "password": "blabla",
      "auth": "blabla"
    }
  }
}
```

vs.

```
{
  "auths": {
    "myregistry.corp": {
      "username": "my-user",
      "password": "blabla",
      "auth": "blabla"
    },
    "project1.myregistry.corp": {
      "username": "my-user",
      "password": "blabla",
      "auth": "blabla"
    },
    "project2.myregistry.corp": {
      "username": "my-user",
      "password": "blabla",
      "auth": "blabla"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on [Kubernetes documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/containers/images/#config-json):

> Kubernetes allows glob URLs as well as prefix-matched paths.

For example, for your use case, the following should be possible:

```json
{
  "auths": {
    "*myregistry.corp": {
      "username": "my-user",
      "password": "blabla",
      "auth": "blabla"
    }
  }
}
```